# Simple version checker with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, oop, signals, slot

I’m trying to implement a simple version checker below. 
I’m getting a zero error code reading the file, but the file
contents show up blank. You can access the file via browser,
permissions are ok.

```
void check_version()
 {
  QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
  QUrl data_url("http://www.example.com/version.txt");
  QNetworkRequest req(data_url);
  QNetworkReply *reply = nam->get(req);
  QByteArray data = reply->readAll() ;
  QString s1(data);
  int err = reply->error();
  QString s2 = QString::number(err);
  delete reply;
  delete nam;

  QMessageBox::critical(0, "",s1+" "+s2,QMessageBox::Cancel);

}
```

I gather the problem is that I need to wait to read until the get is finished, so I need a signal and a slot: the signal tells the slot to read the data.

pseudocode:

```
QObject::connect(&rep, SIGNAL( rep is finished ),
QByteArray newver , SLOT(  reply->readAll()  ));
```

How do I set up a signal/slot for my task?

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you have to wait until the `get()` is "finished" in order to obtain the whole response with a call to `readAll()`.
Following a working example to start with:

```
// ...
QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QUrl data_url("http://www.example.com/version.txt");
QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(data_url));
QEventLoop eventLoop;
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
eventLoop.exec();
if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
{
    // Something went wrong. Error can be retrieved with: reply->error()
}
else
{
    // Call reply->readAll() and do what you need with the data
}
// ...
```

This example will block until the reply is ready. If you need an asynchronous behavior you can just connect the signal `finished()` to a custom `slot` and check for error and/or read there. I do not recommend to connect the signal `finished()` directly to `readAll()` because "sometimes errors happen".

Comment: Thanks! I do get: error: use of undeclared identifier 'connect'
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit())); -- something missing from the .h file?

Comment: @Jocala, that's a context issue. I bet the class in which you're calling `connect()` doesn't inherit `QObject`. Use this instead: `QObject::connect()`